# I cannot send an email from the form on my web to my gmail account with PHP Mailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

As the reference on the subject, I have been struggling to make a system which I can get an email from the form on the website. I use a server, HostGator. What I did is below

1. Created the form on the contact page embraced form tags, having method="POST" action="send.php".
2. Created my mail account on HostGator
3. I filled all the information about the host on send.php which shows a PHP Mailer basic format.

   4.After cricking the button named, "submit", the error shows like "This page isn't working. localhost is currently unable to handle
   this request. HTTP ERROR 500". Thus, I have been stack here now.

The name of my project folder is "businessWeb". The directory of all the folders inside it is below

```
•businessweb/vender/composer/...
•businesswebvender/phpmailer/...

<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require './vendor/autoload.php';

// get variables from the form
$name = filter_var($_POST['name'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message = filter_var($_POST['message'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host ='the address in Incoming section on Cpanel in HostGator ';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'email on hostGator';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '***';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Sender
    $mail->setFrom('email on HostGator', 'Joey Namiki');
    //Recipients
    $mail->addAddress('my gmail account', 'Joey');     
    //Body Content
    $body = "<p>Hello<br /><br /> You have received an enquiry from<br /> " . $name . "<br /><br /> The message is <br />" . $message . "<br /><br />You can contact on <br /> " . $phone . "</p>";

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'JoeyNamiki Website Enquiry from '. $name;
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

    $mail->send();

    header('location: thankyou.php');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Comment: See documentation : https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/outlook-eudora-thunderbird-mac-ipad-phone-client-settings

Comment: @Dilek Thank you. I will take a look!

Comment: 500 errors will show up in your web server’s error log, which you should have access to

Comment: @Synchro I will also check ! Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->Username = 'email on hostGator';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '***';
```

I hope you have changed user name and password for showing on stackoverflow, not in your real code.

You can set SMTPDebug to 1 to view what happening when trying to send email.

Additionaly use of simple mail function on php to test textOnly mail.

And try Comment some additional options in PHPMailer to see if the problem is from them.
for example comment isHTML and AltBody.

Comment: Yes I have already changed them. I set the SMTP declaration in the first two lines of the code, but it did not work. I see. I did not know how to check the bug in PHP. So, I will try to use some. Thank you so much, Hamid.

Comment: SMTPDebug = 1 is no use for this; set it to 2 to see what the server says.